# Calling Python method from C#

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I have created a Jupyter Notebook that has a single method called "Testing".  Then I have created a Core6/C# application that will consume the Testing method. In my Core6 app, I have added pythonnet via NuGet, then I have the codes as shown below:

```
 using Python.Runtime;
 
 using (Py.GIL()){
      // Call to Testing method here.
 }
```

The problem with the codes above, when the `Py.GIL()` is executed, I am getting this error

> The type initializer for 'Delegates' threw an exception.

Any solution to this problem?